# Creating PDF file in C#

Tags: c#, pdf, pdf-generation

I have a form with 2 pictureBoxes and 2 textBoxes.

I need to create PDF where first image (from PictureBox1 is on top half of PDF and textbox1 is on that picture on right under corner of it) same thing with second picture and textBox just on the bottom half of PDF.

Here is my code for creating PDF:

```
private void button14_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Document doc = new Document (iTextSharp.text.PageSize.LETTER, 10, 10, 42, 35);
    PdfWriter wri = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, new FileStream("C:\\Users\\Username\\Desktop\\Test.pdf", FileMode.Create));
    doc.Open();
    Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph("Yo");
    doc.Add(paragraph);
    doc.Close();
}
```

Comment: Line `Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph("Yo");` was just for the test, to make sore that the code works

Comment: I want to make/create 2 images with text on the bottom of them in PDF file. I don't know how to do it

Comment: I figured out I can add these 2 lines of code `            iTextSharp.text.Image png = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(pictureBox.Image);
            doc.Add(png);` but I get 2 errors `Error 2 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Drawing.Image' to 'iTextSharp.text.Image' C:\Users\Username\Desktop\Sitais_Ir_Deladdd - Copy\MainForm.cs 1228 75 MediaPlaybackViewer
` and `Error 1 The best overloaded method match for 'iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(iTextSharp.text.Image)' has some invalid arguments C:\Users\Username\Desktop\Sitais_Ir_Deladdd - Copy\MainForm.cs 1228 41 MediaPlaybackViewer
`